# Understanding OOP (wrt C# and the DateTime class)

Tags: c#, oop, datetime

Please correct my errors that don't make sense logically.

The 'DateTime' class in C# has a method called 'Now', that returns the current date and time in object format.

So, to use it one has to call the class DateTime directly and specify the 'Now' method. Like this:

```
DateTime meLearning = DateTime.Now;
```

and, as I've learnt by trying it out, we can't use this method 'Now' via an object like this:

```
DateTime testObj = new DateTime();
testObj = meLearning.Now;
```

Guess the question now is, why not?
Thought when an instance of a class is created (i.e. an object of that class), all the class methods (like 'Now') are available to the object.

Thinking deeper into it, I know the method 'Now' can not act on an object. So maybe this is a bad example.

But it raises the question if there are some methods that an object has access to and some it doesn't have access to. What are these methods called and how can you tell the difference amongst a lists of methods offered from a class?

Hope my question makes sense. All response welcomed.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the intellisense (this text that comes up when you write) you can see that DateTime.Now has a "return type" meaning that it will return an `object`. Callin `new Datetime()` only creates a empty datetime object. To see what Datetime or aything can do then click the thing you want to check and then F12 (you will now get the description of the object)

Comment: Cheers @Thomas. Used read the intellisense. Just didn't answer my question about using it via the class instance. Will now read up on class properties/members. Cheers guys.

Comment: By the way, DateTime is a "struct", not a "class" - but that doesn't influence this particular question

Comment: Not strictly related, just an interesting addition. Eric Lippert now says that `DateTime.Now` was a mistake in retrospect. It should have been a method, something like `DateTime.GetCurrentDateTime()`. Source: http://ericlippert.com/2014/05/19/when-should-i-write-a-property/

Answer (score 2):

`Now` is not a method - it's a `static` property - you cannot use it on an instance because it`s`static`

---

you can see the difference just by `DateTime.Now` vs. `myTimeInstance.Now`

and you can see it on it's definition:

```
public static DateTime Now { get; }
```

see it's defined as a static member, returning an `DateTime` instance with just an getter (ofc. the real implementation will have said getter and retrieve the current system time)

BTW: the design choice is not really great as it's making code that uses this hard to test

---

you can find more information on *static classes and static members* on the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this @Carsten

Answer (score 2):

DateTime.Now is a static property, which can only be called on the type and not on an instance.

From google:

> The Static Keyword. In C# terms, “static” means “relating to the type
>   itself, rather than an instance of the type”. You access a static
>   member using the type name instead of a reference or a value, e.g.
>   Guid.NewGuid().

So static properties/methods are prefixed with static keyword. Visual Studio automatically filter the methods you can call on type and instance.

Comment: Thanks for this @somdoron

Answer (score 1):

The methods `.Now` and `.UtcNow` are instead `static` properties of the DateTime Class so you have to call them through the Class not instances.

You can consult the [original source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,b0d5e4c9a8d4ddac,references) to see their actual signature.

You can also consult [this article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/static-property) about what a `static` property is, and how to use it in C#

Comment: Thanks for this @r1verside

Answer (score 0):

Static methods or properties can be called on types and there is only one copy of static methods and properties inside memory for all objects.

Non static methods can be called on instances and each object can have its own copy of methods and properties inside memory.

Because DateTime.Now is **current**, and this is correct for all objects there is no need that each DateTime object has its own **current** date that is why Now is static are equal for all DateTimes.